# Duplicate Records created by find_or_create In Rails+Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have an object `Message` which is only ever created by this line:

```
Message.find_or_create_by(:api_id => params['message_id'])
```

In theory, I should never have two messages with the same api_id, but... I do. It happens when two requests happen simultaneously that both call that line.

Someone else has posted the same problem with ActiveRecord: [Duplicate Records created by find_or_create_by_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163125/duplicate-records-created-by-find-or-create-by) But I am using Mongoid.

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: AR doing it wrong is one thing. Mongoid is specifically designed on top of MongoDB and should use perfectly atomic upserts for this. No option to move to using the driver directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution using upserts:

```
Message.collection.update({:api_id => params['message_id']}, {'$set' => {:api_id => params['message_id']}}, :upsert => true)
@message = Message.where(:api_id => params['message_id']).first
```

Feels a little messy, but works. Still open to alternatives.

Comment: I've had to use this same solution.  It's worth noting that **no callbacks will be called** when this document is initialized/created/saved.